# Duplicates variable with excel

Tags: excel

I want to delete the repetitions of randomly sorted values. There are no repeating values in the columns. But I don't want a value in the first column to be in the second column.The first time an existing value needs to be deleted every time it is repeated.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcCBv.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXql2.png) With this macro, the first repeated values are deleted. And there is no repeated value, but this deletion must come from the end to the beginning.

Comment: If your range is just a single rectangle, you can either: use two nested For...Next cycle with step -1 to cover all the cells in a reversed order; edit the code you are using now by taking the coordinates of each myCell and using them to target the cell that "mirrors" it.

Comment: There are data in 589 rows and 22 columns. But there are spaces between the values. I would be very grateful if you could help me how to write this code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to integrate this function in your code:

```
Function FunOppositeCell(RngCell As Range, RngRange As Range) As Range
    
    'This function return the cell inside RngRange opposite to RngCell.
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim IntY As Integer
    Dim IntX As Integer
    
    'If RngCell is not inside RngRange, FunOppositeCell returns Nothing.
    If Intersect(RngCell, RngRange) Is Nothing Then
        Set FunOppositeCell = Nothing
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    'If RngRange has multiple areas, FunOppositeCell returns Nothing.
    If RngRange.Areas.Count > 1 Then
        Set FunOppositeCell = Nothing
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    'The row of the opposite cell (inside RngRange) is obtained by summing the _
     row number of the top left cell of RngRange with its rows count; we then _
     substract the row of RngCell. Similar process is used to obtain the column _
     of the opposite cell (inside RngRange).
    IntY = RngRange.Cells(1, 1).Row + RngRange.Rows.Count - RngCell.Row
    IntX = RngRange.Cells(1, 1).Column + RngRange.Columns.Count - RngCell.Column
    
    'Setting FunOppositeCell.
    Set FunOppositeCell = RngRange.Cells(IntY, IntX)
    
End Function
```

You'll just need to use `FunOppositeCell(myCell)` instead of `myCell` inside of your `For...Next` cycle and it will redirect the focus the the opposite cell.